# Can't download engine when migrating for the first time

Tags: database, prisma

Im trying to run `npx prisma migrate dev` (or any prisma command I guess) and It does this:

```
Downloading Prisma engines for Node-API for windows [=============       ] 63%
```

Then quits the output and brings up the cli input again. No error output  or anything. What's going on?

I was expecting the cli to start migrating my schema to the database.